# Registration Form

Tags: 2013, form

I would like some guidance to:

1. Create a form for Events
2. Allow people to Register for the Event created from (1)

I would prefer if the above can be achieved solely by SharePoint Designer 2013.

Any assistance are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom list `Events` (You can also use a Calendar list to start with)
2. Add fields you want to capture as part of an Event (Like Date, Event Title, etc.)
3. Create another list Registration
4. Add a field which is a look up to `Events` list

The above will be to your base solution or schema. Now you can enhance the solution using `JSLinks` etc to give a good user experience to the end user.